# How to arrange while loop, echo, if statement, echo, else statement, and finally close the entire div

Tags: php, html

I have some code which I want to display like this:

Posts and and the comments on those posts.

I want to echo "all the comments"; if a post has atleast one comment else echo "no comments".

Below is my code which doesnt work in terms of the if else statement and the divs. Thanks for your help.
 The codes starts from the while loop.Rest works fine:

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

      $fname =$row['fname'];
      $sname=$row['sname'];
      $id=$row['poster_id'];
      $id2=$row['commenter_id'];
      $email=$row['email'];
      $profile_pic=$row['profile_pic'];
      $city=$row['city'];
      $country=$row['country'];
      $search_date=$row['search_date'];
      $QUERY=$row['QUERY'];
      $search_id=$row['search_id'];
      $comment=$row['comment'];

      //-displays the result of the array

    echo "<div style='border-radius: 25px; border: 1px solid #73AD21; padding: 20px; width: 90%;'> <a  href=\"user.php?id=$id\">".'<img src="'.htmlentities($row["poster_photo"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'" alt="Avatar" style="max-width:50px;max-height:50px;" />'."  ".$row["poster_fname"]. "  ".$row["poster_sname"]." </a> around <span style='color:#04B486;'>".$row["poster_city"]."  </span>in <span style='color:green;'>".$row["poster_country"]." </span> </span> on <span style='color:blue;'>".$row["search_date"]." </span><div style='margin-left:8%;'> I am looking for <span style='color:green;'>".$row["QUERY"]." </div></span> </br><span class='metoo'> &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this if you also need similar assistance!'><img src='images/icons/meetoo.png' alt='me too' style='width:20px;height:20px;'></a><a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this if you also need similar assistance!'>Me too</a> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this to direct a friend!'><img src='images/icons/advise.png' alt='advise' style='width:20px;height:20px;'></a><a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this to direct a friend!'>Advise</a> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<a href=\"user.php?id=$id\" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this if you will sort out this issue 100%!'><img src='images/icons/assist.png' alt='me too' style='width:15px;height:15px;'></a>  <a href=\"user.php?id=$id\" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this if you will sort out this issue 100%!'>Assist</a> &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</span> </br> </br>


   <?php if ($comment !== 'NULL'){ 

     echo '<div style='margin-left:35%; font-size:80%'> <center><u style='font-size:75%;'><strong> Advises </strong> </u></center></br> <a  href=\"user.php?id=$id2\">".'<img src="'.htmlentities($row["commenter_photo"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'" alt="Avatar" style="max-width:50px;max-height:50px;" />'."  ".$row["commenter_fname"]. "  ".$row["commenter_sname"]." </a> said: <span style='color:blue;'>".$row["comment"]." </span><span style='margin-left:8%;'> on <span style='color:green;'>".$row["comment_date"]." </span></span> </br>;'
      }else {
     echo 'Nothing to show';
     }
    ?>
     </div>



          </div> 

          </br>"; 

                }




               ?>
```

Comment: you cant echo php tags inside php tags.. your code is extremely confused.

Comment: So, what is the best format?

Comment: the best solution is by reading first some tutorial http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php

Answer (score 0):

Can you try in this below format,

```
  <?php
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<div style='border-radius: 25px; border: 1px solid #73AD21; padding: 20px; width: 90%;'>";
    echo "<a  href='user.php?id=".$id."'>";
    echo "<img src='".htmlentities($row["poster_photo"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."' alt='Avatar' style='max-width:50px;max-height:50px;' />";
    ...
    ....
    ...        
    if ($comment !== 'NULL'){ 
     echo "<div style='margin-left:35%; font-size:80%'> <center><u style='font-size:75%;'><strong> Advises </strong> </u></center></br> ";
     echo "<a  href='user.php?id=".$id2."'>";
     echo "<img src='".htmlentities($row["commenter_photo"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."' alt='Avatar' style='max-width:50px;max-height:50px;' />".$row["commenter_fname"]. "  ".$row["commenter_sname"]." </a> said: <span style='color:blue;'>".$row["comment"]."</span><span style='margin-left:8%;'> on <span style='color:green;'>".$row["comment_date"]." </span></span> </br>";
     }else {
        echo 'Nothing to show';
     }
     echo "</div></div></br>";
 }
 ?>
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: This one shows even when there is no comment. I already have done it. I need when post has no comment, display "no commments". In my case, first echo displays the post and second, displays the comments on that post.

Answer (score 0):

Just formatted your code, but you still need to check quotes (") or ('), that they are managed properly.

```
echo "<div style='border-radius: 25px; border: 1px solid #73AD21; padding: 20px; width: 90%;'> 

<a  href=\"user.php?id=$id\">".'
  <img src="'.htmlentities($row["poster_photo"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'" alt="Avatar" style="max-width:50px;max-height:50px;" />'."  ".$row["poster_fname"]. "  ".$row["poster_sname"]." 
</a> around 
<span style='color:#04B486;'>".$row["poster_city"]."  </span>
in <span style='color:green;'>".$row["poster_country"]." </span> 
on <span style='color:blue;'>".$row["search_date"]." </span>
<div style='margin-left:8%;'> I am looking for 
<span style='color:green;'>".$row["QUERY"]." </span>
</div> 
</br>
<span class='metoo'> &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this if you also need similar assistance!'>
  <img src='images/icons/meetoo.png' alt='me too' style='width:20px;height:20px;'>
</a>
<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this if you also need similar assistance!'>Me too</a>
 &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this to direct a friend!'>
  <img src='images/icons/advise.png' alt='advise' style='width:20px;height:20px;'>
</a>
<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this to direct a friend!'>Advise</a> 
&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
<a href=\"user.php?id=$id\" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this if you will sort out this issue 100%!'>
  <img src='images/icons/assist.png' alt='me too' style='width:15px;height:15px;'>
</a>  
<a href=\"user.php?id=$id\" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click this if you will sort out this issue 100%!'>Assist</a> &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</span> </br> </br>"; // added after the comment

 if ($comment !== 'NULL')
 { 
     echo "<div style='margin-left:35%; font-size:80%'> <center><u style='font-size:75%;'>
<strong> Advises </strong> </u></center></br> 
<a  href=\"user.php?id=$id2\">".
'<img src="'.htmlentities($row["commenter_photo"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'" alt="Avatar" style="max-width:50px;max-height:50px;" />'."  ".$row["commenter_fname"]. "  ".$row["commenter_sname"]." </a> said: 
<span style='color:blue;'>".$row["comment"]." </span>
<span style='margin-left:8%;'> on <span style='color:green;'>".$row["comment_date"]." </span></span> </br>";
      }else {
     echo 'Nothing to show';
     }
    ?>
     </div>
</div> 
       <?php     } // issue was it was taken as html as php tags were not included

           ?>
```

Comment: Thanks very much... only that it has this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ',' or ';' in line 196. What is this and where do we place this ; ?

Comment: Check the code I have edited it @BrianWambua, before `if` we needed to put `;`

Comment: Nop... it is very disturbing with Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in line 187....

Comment: I've fixed `;` issue on one more line, @BrianWambua. Still can you tell what is on line 187

Comment: echo '<div style='margin-left:35%; font-size:80%'> <center><u style='font-size:75%;'>

Comment: @BrianWambua, I've fixed the issue for that line, as I already mentioned **you still need to check quotes (") or ('), that they are managed properly** and that was the only issue

Comment: Ok.. now this issue: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in line 227.  which is last line with no code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper format to concatenate in PHP

```
<?php 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $id=$row['poster_id'];
    $id2=$row['commenter_id'];
    echo '<div style="float:left"><a href="user.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="'.htmlentities($row["poster_photo"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'"></a>';
        if ($comment !== 'NULL')
        { 
            echo '<div style="float:left"><a href="user.php?id='.$id2.'"><img src="'.htmlentities($row["commenter_photo"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'"></a>';
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Nothing to show';
        }
        echo '</div>'; 
    echo '</div>' ;
    echo '</br>' ;
}
?>
```